# firejail --x11=xephyr goes to sleep after 10 minutes

Tags: screensaver, firejail, xephyr

I run any program through Firejail using the option X11 xephyr (to isolate X11).

A separate program window opens as it should, but after 10 minutes of inactivity the screen goes dark. If you move the mouse, it comes out of hibernation mode. How can I disable hibernation mode?